# Unique Task ID for each task of long running complex process

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a project which executes 100s of tasks simultaneously to perform complex activities which include a number of methods and multiple DB I/Os. To log all activities I use SQLite DB. Since all tasks writes log simultaneously so it is not meaningful if we read log sequentially so i used Task Id to distinguish each task's sequence of activities but unfortunately there is no guarantee that Task id will always be unique. Unlike thread where we can set thread name by assigning GUID using `Thread.CurrentThread.Name`

Further more Task Id is just a number and it always starts with 1 so there are a number of records with same id in log file which are actually do not belong to one task. Can anyone share expertise how to have/maintain a unique Task.ID for each Task across multiple asynchronous executions of application?

More explicitly, I need to traverse in log file to monitor sequence of activities of a specific Task by using Task ID (or by some other way) which currently not possible due to asynchronous insertions of log records by number of tasks simultaneously.

Comment: You need to create an instance for each process.  The instance will contain unique properties for each process which is equivalent to a Task ID.

Comment: You can wrap the functionality to your own class and use unique id by yourself (for example the GUID). Or you can use `.GetHashCode()` wich is not guaranteed to be unique, but there is high change it will be.

Comment: What type of tasks does your application create? Are these [delegate-based](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) (`Task.Run` with synchronous delegate) or [promise-style](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/04/a-tour-of-task-part-10-promise-tasks.html) (async methods)? Or a mix of both?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Task.Run with synchronous

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in this sentence? *"Task Id is just a number and it always starts with 1 so there are a number of records with same id in log file which are actually do not belong to one task."* Why don't they belong to one task? And how would it be different if the [`Task.Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id) property was of type `string` instead of `int`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks for your response. If i stop the program and start again then Task ID stars from 1. Task.Id is of Int32 types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id?view=net-5.0

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want the `Task.Id` to be unique across multiple consecutive executions of the program. I think that you should edit your question and include this information. What should happen though in case that two or more instances of your program are running concurrently? Would you like to establish an inter-process communication between all running processes, so that a unique id is negotiated for each individual task of each process?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i think you got it what I exactly looking for. I need to traverse in log file to monitor sequence of activities of a specific Task which currently not possible due to asynchronous insertions number of tasks simultaneously.

Comment: Couldn't you combine the `Task.Id` with some "Execution id", to get a practically unique combination? For example #98/240 would mean the 240th task of the 98th execution of the program.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I like the idea of a composite key, execution ID and task ID. This allows easy collation of log statements even if the task ID is not unique. I think it is a partial answer and I would like to see that expanded in the answer section.

Comment: @S.ATTA.M, "Suggested edit queue is full". Please can you update your question to make it explicit that you want a unique `Task.Id` across multiple executions of your application.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the idea of combine ID is good but in this case i will have to pass this combined ID to all methods which write log.

Comment: @DanielDearlove question edited as per you suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @S.ATTA.M, all answers seem to point to [mericless refactoring](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/refactor.html). If you have a lot of `Task.CurrentId` parameters in your logging statements, maybe there is an efficient way to prepend or append that to a logging statement by writing a logging adapter (method or class). That way , `Task.CurrentId` appears in one place in your code then it is easy to add an "execution ID" later.

Comment: Honestly I think that the last edit ([revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68002177/3)) made the question more confusing, instead of clarifying it. My suggestion is to rework the question, simplify the language, include your current implementation of the method that writes the logs, include a sample of your current logs, and include a sample of the logs as you would like them to be.

Answer (score 1):

The ID is not guaranteed to be unique (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Id)). If you need a unique ID for each `Task` then it sounds like you need an adapter for a `TaskFactory`:

```
class TaskWrapper
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Task Task { get; set; }
}

public class TaskWrapperFactory
{
    private object lockobj = new object();
    private int nextId = 0;

    public TaskWrapper StartNew(Action action)
    {
        int id = 0;
        
        lock(this.lockobj)
        {
            id = this.nextId;
            this.nextId++;
        }

        return new TaskWrapper
        {
            ID = id,
            Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Its a good idea but i will have to carry on this object to all nested methods which can be around 100. Unlike if we create task Task.Run(()=>{ SomeMethod()}); and SomeMethod( ) calls SomeAnotherMethod() then in all nested method we can retrieve task id by just calling "Task.CurrentId" without passing any reference from calling method. How we can achieve the same?

Comment: @S.ATTA.M, `Task.CurrentId` is not mutable so you any permanent solution will require code changes, even if they are just copy-and-paste. I was already aware of Thread Local Storage and, it turns out, there is "Task Local Storage" too. See [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1) for details. It looks like you can update the `TaskWrapperFactory` with a static `CurrentId` property that can obtain the unique ID of each task. Also, you would have to consistently use your own factory method too.

Comment: @S.ATTA.M, all the methods that call `Task.CurrentId` become aware of the context in which they are executed which, for me, was a bad smell. It turns out that it follows the [Ambient Context (anti-) pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-ambient-context-anti-pattern/) and that might be a good target for refactoring. If possible, try to feed in all the parameters you need when you start the task. This will make it easier to test because you do not need to worry about any ambient contexts.